# Power BI Pie chart interactive

Tags: powerbi

I am using the pie chart to show single values as a summary:

[image: pie chart]

When I select the pie chart I would like the tables to be filtered out but this isnt happening. Any advise on how I can get these to filter out on tables?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about how you set up the other visuals? Are they filtering each other? Are they related to each other in your model?

Comment: It is bad paratice to use a pie chart for single values, it you need to provide a summary use a card visual.  As you are not providing a category to the visual, how it it going to know what to slice it by?